# Add multiple strings to the end of multiple spreadsheet rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a single column of data containing rows of (hyperlinks):

- website-a.com
- website-b.com
- website-c.com
- website-d.com

I am trying to add =0, =5, =10 & =15 on the end of these sites, so that the data ends up as follows:

- website-a.com=0
- website-a.com=5
- website-a.com=10
- website-a.com=15
- website-b.com=0
- website-b.com=5
- website-b.com=10
- website-b.com=15
- website-c.com=0
- website-c.com=5
- website-c.com=10
- website-c.com=15
- website-d.com=0
- website-d.com=5
- website-d.com=10
- website-d.com=15

The only way that I can think to do this is to manually concatenate each url 4 times in Excel, but in my production requirements this is not practical as I have 100's of URLs & 1000's of numbers to be placed.

An thoughts as to how I could easily undertake this task?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've ended up building a workbook with two sheets.

The first sheet has my core urls on (1 per row).

Then the second sheet concatenates each of the urls several times:

- =CONCATENATE(sheet1:A1,"=0",sheet1:A1,"=5",sheet1:A1,"=10",sheet1:A1,"=15")
- =CONCATENATE(sheet1:B1,"=0",sheet1:B1,"=5",sheet1:B1,"=10",sheet1:B1,"=15")
- etc...

Once this has been done, I export the sheet to csv.  Then open this sheet in TextEdit / Notepad, & then copy the text into MS Word.  Then I search for paragraph mark (^p) & replace it with blank.

I then find & replace http with manual line break http (^lhttp).  This then gives me the required entries one per line.